# Can we continue doing work while macro is running on another MS-WORD instance?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is it possible to run another microsoft word instance while macros is running in any of document?
Currently I am not able to run what I am asking for.

My code overview is below.

```
With ActiveDocument.Range
If .Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
URL = .Hyperlinks(1).Address
With IE
    .Visible = False
    .navigate URL
Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
IE.ExecWB 17, 0 '// SelectAll
IE.ExecWB 12, 2 '// Copy selection
End With
some paste and formate
```

The problem with above code is as it does .readyState = 4, I am not able to do any work. Is there any solution to my problem?

**Edit**
After having some knowledge from comments, I would like to add.

I have saved VBA in word module. Can I run that macro asynchronously from anywhere else by opening specific document, and still continue working on other document of word.
I tried that from excel but still I was not able to open any other word instance.

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747877/asynchronous-file-downloads-from-within-vba-excel.

Comment: I don't know how that applies here as I don't have any knowledge of excel VBA. What I am asking that is there any way I can still working with word while VBA is running?

Comment: FWIW, you could certainly work in a different INSTANCE of the Word application. But a different window does not mean a different instance. Word is pseudoSDI meaning it opens multiple windows within the same application instance. The question is, whether you want to start a new instance as part of your code, as a different macro, as an icon...

Comment: You have to use asynchronous operation, that question provide you with the how to download a file from internet asynchronously.

Comment: @CindyMeister: I want above vba to run in one window and continue working in another window.

Comment: @Jules: I will try that method and get back.