# How can you get VBA to start downloading a file and not wait for it to finish before continuing to the next line code

Tags: vba, download

I'm trying to optimize a VBA application that generates a report.

This report requires the application to download and embed multiple images.
I've identified this as the biggest bottle neck in the application.

My first attempt was to get VBA to execute a Powershell command that would download the images early on in the generation of the report and then the application would embed them from the HD after it was done crunching data.
Do to obvious security concerns my work environment prevents VBA from executing shell scripts.

After a few unimportant failed attempts (trying to open another/this xlsm workbook with a new excel application independently of my vba thread with an on open execution and variations of this) I've come here asking for suggestions.

How would you use vba to start downloading image (using any native windows 10 application/command/process/...) and not wait for the download to complete before moving onto the next line of code?

Later on in the application I'll have code to scan the destination directory to determine if the files are done being downloaded if not it'll sleep and repeat x times before fail.

**Update**: Based on the comments I think I'm very close to a solution. I've included the code I'm currently working with at the bottom of this update. The problem now is that it quickly downloads the file as long as I have made a request to the same url at least once before.
On the first request it hangs on 'oXMLHTTP.send' for a period of time a little greater than what I would expect it would take to download the file through a browser and then for some reason resizes itself.

Could anyone help me with this hanging issue and / or explain why this code calls 'Workbook_WindowResize'?

This happens on and off my works VPN. Looking at Fiddler I can tell that only two requests get sent out.

Result 200: http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/50MB.zip?randomizer=ff%2014
Result 200: http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/50MB.zip?randomizer=ee%20761

**Result and Code**

In a brand new workbook I pasted the code found at the end of this update.
This is what it I got in the immediate window.

```
A took: 33375milliseconds
Pre DoEvents
Workbook_WindowResized
Post DoEvents
B took: 593milliseconds
Pre DoEvents
Post DoEvents
C took: 33797milliseconds
Pre DoEvents
Workbook_WindowResized
Post DoEvents
Do work
Pre DoEvents
Post DoEvents
a done
b done
c done
```

ThisWorkbook Code

```
Private mlngStart As Long
Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Public Sub StartTimer()
    mlngStart = GetTickCount
End Sub

Public Function EndTimer() As Long
    EndTimer = (GetTickCount - mlngStart)
End Function

Function StartDownload(ByVal vWebFile As String, sPath As String) As Object
    Dim oXHTTP As Object
    Dim oStream As Object


    Set oXHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    Application.StatusBar = "Fetching " & vWebFile & " as " & sPath
    oXHTTP.Open "GET", vWebFile, False
    oXHTTP.send
    With oStream
        .Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
        .Open
        .Write oXHTTP.responseBody
        .SaveToFile sPath, 2 'adSaveCreateOverWrite
        .Close
    End With
    Set StartDownload = oXHTTP
    Set oStream = Nothing
    Application.StatusBar = False

End Function

Sub FinishDownload(ByRef oXMLHTTP, ByVal vLocalFile As String)

    'Wait for request to finish
    Do While oXMLHTTP.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
Function foo()
    Dim dest As String
    dest = "C:\sandbox\"
    Dim a, b, c As Object
    DoEvents
    Url = "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/50MB.zip?randomizer=ff" & Str(Math.Round(Math.Rnd(12) * 1000, 0))
    Call StartTimer
    Set a = StartDownload(Url, dest & "a.zip")
    Debug.Print "A took: " & EndTimer & "milliseconds"
    
    Debug.Print "Pre DoEvents"
    DoEvents
    Debug.Print "Post DoEvents"
    
    Call StartTimer
    Set b = StartDownload(Url, dest & "b.zip")
    Debug.Print "B took: " & EndTimer & "milliseconds"
    
    Debug.Print "Pre DoEvents"
    DoEvents
    Debug.Print "Post DoEvents"
    
    Url = "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/50MB.zip?randomizer=ee" & Str(Math.Round(Math.Rnd(12) * 1000, 0))
    
    Call StartTimer
    Set c = StartDownload(Url, dest & "c.zip")
    Debug.Print "C took: " & EndTimer & "milliseconds"
    
    Debug.Print "Pre DoEvents"
    DoEvents
    Debug.Print "Post DoEvents"
    
    Debug.Print ("Do work")
    Call bar
        
    Debug.Print "Pre DoEvents"
    DoEvents
    Debug.Print "Post DoEvents"
    
    Call FinishDownload(a, dest & "a.zip")
    Debug.Print ("a done")
    Call FinishDownload(b, dest & "b.zip")
    Debug.Print ("b done")
    Call FinishDownload(c, dest & "c.zip")
    Debug.Print ("c done")
End Function

Function Download_File(ByVal vWebFile As String, ByVal vLocalFile As String) As Boolean
    Dim oXMLHTTP As Object, i As Long, vFF As Long, oResp() As Byte

    'You can also set a ref. to Microsoft XML, and Dim oXMLHTTP as MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", vWebFile, False 'Open socket to get the website
    oXMLHTTP.send 'send request

    'Wait for request to finish
    Do While oXMLHTTP.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
    Loop

    oResp = oXMLHTTP.responseBody 'Returns the results as a byte array

    'Create local file and save results to it
    vFF = FreeFile
    If Dir(vLocalFile) <> "" Then Kill vLocalFile
    Open vLocalFile For Binary As #vFF
    Put #vFF, , oResp
    Close #vFF

    'Clear memory
    Set oXMLHTTP = Nothing
End Function

Sub bar()
    Dim F As Integer
    F = FreeFile
    Open "C:\sandbox\" & "\example.txt" For Output As F
    Close #F
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_WindowResize(ByVal Wn As Window)
    Debug.Print "Workbook_WindowResized"
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747877/asynchronous-file-downloads-from-within-vba-excel

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I've tried to implement the code in post but sadly it still waits for the request to complete. Please check the post update for details.

Comment: As noted in the post I linked, that example I posted for binary download is *synchronous* - you'd use  `oXHTTP.Open "GET", vWebFile, True` for an asynchronous fetch.

Comment: Here's an example file:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wPVD3PD6c83TE3XWuOWrNvV8HqAk0GPH/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

From the links provided by @Tim Williams in the comments I created this and it works.

```
Function StartDownload(ByVal vWebFile As String) As Object
    Dim oXMLHTTP As Object, i As Long, vFF As Long, oResp() As Byte

    'You can also set a ref. to Microsoft XML, and Dim oXMLHTTP as MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", vWebFile, True'Open socket to get the website
    oXMLHTTP.Send 'send request
    Set StartDownload = oXMLHTTP
End Function

Sub FinishDownload(ByRef oXMLHTTP, ByVal vLocalFile As String)

    'Wait for request to finish
    Do While oXMLHTTP.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
    Loop

    oResp = oXMLHTTP.responseBody 'Returns the results as a byte array

    'Create local file and save results to it
    vFF = FreeFile
    If Dir(vLocalFile) <> "" Then Kill vLocalFile
    Open vLocalFile For Binary As #vFF
    Put #vFF, , oResp
    Close #vFF

    'Clear memory
    Set oXMLHTTP = Nothing
End Sub
Function foo()
    Dim dest As String
    dest = "C:\sandbox\"
    url = "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/200MB.zip"
    Dim a, b, c As Object
    DoEvents
    Set a = DownloadManager.StartDownload(url)
    DoEvents
    Set b = DownloadManager.StartDownload(url)
    DoEvents
    Set c = DownloadManager.StartDownload(url)
    DoEvents
    Debug.Print ("Do Something")
    
    Call FinishDownload(a, dest & "a.zip")
    Debug.Print ("a done")
    
    Call FinishDownload(b, dest & "b.zip")
    Debug.Print ("b done")
    Call FinishDownload(c, dest & "c.zip")
    Debug.Print ("c done")
End Function
```