# VBA code hangs while opening a file from URL

Tags: vba

I am trying to directly open an axf file in excel and then using my other functions I format the data. The problem I am having is sometimes the file opens without any delay and sometimes it never open and hangs the excel.

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim OriginalSecuritySetting As MsoAutomationSecurity
sCSVLink = "http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDQ60801/IDQ60801.99367.axf"
sfile = "IDQ60801.99367.axf"
ssheet = "Hay_Point_Data"

Set wnd = ActiveWindow
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets(ssheet).Cells.ClearContents

OriginalSecuritySetting = Application.AutomationSecurity
Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
Workbooks.Open Filename:=sCSVLink

End Sub
```

Please advise how can I make it to run every time. Thanks

Comment: The hang is due to the server being slow to respond - you can't fix that from your side.  You could maybe try to download the file asynchronously so that Excel doesn't lock up while waiting.  Eg see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747877/asynchronous-file-downloads-from-within-vba-excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this: [How do I download a file using VBA (without Internet Explorer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877389/how-do-i-download-a-file-using-vba-without-internet-explorer)
Answered by [Ole Henrik Skogstrøm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/900271/ole-henrik-skogstr%C3%B8m)
To open the same file, you need to import the data type, in this way, it is possible to identify the workbook and finish its adjustments.
Good Luck

```
Sub DownloadFile()

Dim myURL As String
Dim SrtPath As String
Dim SrtFile As String

myURL = "http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDQ60801/IDQ60801.99367.axf"

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "username", "password"
WinHttpReq.send

SrtPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "IDQ60801.yourname.axf"
If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile SrtPath, 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
    oStream.Close
End If
Workbooks.Open Filename:=SrtPath
End Sub
```